# Authenticate users in User Pool with google using User Pool Federation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Do I understand correctly, that users can authunticate with User Pool Federation only using AWS UI. I should open URL like:
`https://${some_name}.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=${responseType}&client_id=${clientId}&state=${state}&scope=${scope}`

There will be Amazon login form. User can login/register using this form and then he will be redirected to ${redirectUrl} with tokens. The problem that this form works only for WEB. In mobile applications you can't sign in google using WEB VIEW. Is it possible to authenticate with Google in User Pool in mobile applications?